# How to allign a treeview childjust below the parent?

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, treeview, telerik-grid

I have 3 columns and 4 rows.
In each row first and second column contains a textblock  and third column contains button .
Second row is just alligned below the first one.

But in the in the third row i have a TreeView and all the child of tree view disturbs the allignment. It shifts the the child textblocks in little right (because treeview's child are always in bit right).
**I want to position them (allign) exactly below the textbox of its parent. Is it possible to do so ?**

Currently it is like this:

[image]

But i want like this:

[image]

My code is like this:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView Grid.Row="2" Name="RadTreeViewObj" Margin="10" Background="{StaticResource BGBrush_1}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BGBrush_1}" ItemsSource="{Binding EODDataStepsCollection}" SelectionMode="Single" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}">
    <telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedItems}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <toolkit:BusyIndicator Grid.Column="0" BusyContent="Server requesting ..." IsBusy="{Binding IsRequested}" DisplayAfter="0" Padding="0">
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Label}" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" Height="23" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Foreground="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource EODStatusFGConverter}}" />
                </toolkit:BusyIndicator>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding StatusLabel}" Margin="10" Height="23" Width="170" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Foreground="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource EODStatusFGConverter}}" />

                <toolkit:BusyIndicator HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="2" BusyContent="Server requesting ..." IsBusy="{Binding IsRequested}" DisplayAfter="0" Padding="0">
                    <Button Content="{Binding ButtonLabel}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle_Blue}" Padding="5" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" IsEnabled="{Binding StepEnabled}" Command="{Binding ButtonStepCommand}" />
                </toolkit:BusyIndicator>

            </Grid>
        </telerik:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </telerik:RadTreeView.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

How to allign the child of tree view just below (not in right) ?

Comment: I haven't used Telerik for WPF but I would guess you can customize the layout using a Style like the standard WPF controls. There's an example of that here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17379/Advanced-Custom-TreeView-Layout-in-WPF . You'd have to look into the Telerik docs to see what they support for styling.